# How do I embed 2 css in 1 Html?

Tags: html, css

Head section

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kaffehaus Mannfredo | Home</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../1_pics/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylehseet" type="text/css" href="../2_css/general.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../2_css/nav.css">
  <link href='fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' ; rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

First CSS

```
ul {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

li {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
margin:0px;
float: none;
display: inline-block;
}    

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px 17px;
text-decoration: none;}  

li a.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #555;
color: white;}

.navbar-nav {
width: 100%;
text-align: center; }
```

Second CSS

```
body {background-color: black;}
```

I am trying to add 2 CSS files in 1 html. The second one is not working.

In the first one  I format my navbar, in the second I want to make a basic layout for the whole page, any tips?

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: Post the code you have so far. Then tell us what you expected to see and how it's not working, siting any specific errors that get thrown and what line(s) cause them.

Comment: Are you trying to include two sets of style tags within the head? Or link to two external css files?

Comment: The whole second sheet wont work, e.g. background, if i want to set a background in the second css it wont change anything on my site.

Comment: There's nothing special about using multiple stylesheets. Sounds like you have a problem with your link tag? Maybe the file path is incorrect? Post your code.

Comment: put `<link href="css1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> ` and `<link href="css2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> ` inside your `<head>` section

Comment: Share your code please! HTML too

Comment: <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Kaffehaus Mannfredo | Home</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../1_pics/favicon.ico"/>
 <link rel="stylehseet" type="text/css" href="../2_css/general.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../2_css/nav.css">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>     Thats my head

Comment: are you using `body{}` anywhere inside nav.css?

Answer (score 2):

This line is invalid

`<link href='fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' ; rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Remove the semi colon

`<link href='fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Semi colons are used for property value pairs not for use randomly inside of a `<link>` tag.

Comment: The semicolon was a typo as i posted it, i cant find it in my original code.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide your code.

If I understand correctly one CSS is working and the other is not so probably there is an error in your syntax. 
Check that you have the correct path for the CSS files and the correct names. If you copied and pasted it be sure that you changed the name of the second. 
Bellow is an example of two different CSS files named 1 and 2 that are inside a folder named css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "css/1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "css/2.css" />
```

If your files are not in a folder just remove the "css/" part.

Comment: I did exactly that, jet i still cant get it to work, both css are in the same folder but with different names.

Comment: Try removing the CSS that is working and see if there are changes made by the second one

Comment: No it doesnt change anything, it jsut removes the formating from my nav. Yet i wont have abackground for the page.

Comment: Check the extension of the second file and be sure it is .css

Comment: I checked it is a css, i jsut realised aswell if i just simply write something in my body it wont appear, so badically my whole body wont be shown.

Comment: Then there might be an issue with the code in general. Add the HTML part as well

Comment: I found the error now through a validator, yet it didnt change anything i can see, ill try to figure this our myself from now on thanks so far.

Comment: All right, please mark this as solved then

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all of your files are loading?

Press F12 and check the console,
It will give

```
uncaught error failed to load
```

or something similar

Comment: It didnt give me an error as i checked.

Comment: that means that everything is loading correctly

Comment: try this try using this 

    <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
instead of 

    <body background-color="#E6E6FA">

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many css as you want.

Either from external files with :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE">
```

Or inside your html file with :

```
<style>
  /* ...Some css...*/
</style>
```

If there are conflicts between the two css (styling the same element), you need to add specificity because the second one is overriding the first one.

For example :

```
/* first css file */
h1{
  color:blue;
}

/* second css file */
h1{
  color:red;
}
```

In this case, `h1` will be red everywhere.

So In the first css file you have to be more specific by adding a class, or id to the selector :

```
/* first css file */
.navbar h1{
  color:blue;
}
```

Take a look at [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)